# Safari on iPad box-sizing vs all other desktop browsers

Tags: ipad, css, cross-browser

Safari on iPad is displaying a div element with a border taller in height than the desktop browsers including desktop Safari, Chrome, Firefox.  Is there any reason why box-sizing is behaving differently on mobile Apple devices.  See demo here ...  http://jsfiddle.net/froze1906/C43Gn/2/

Comment: I don't have an Ipad, so, I can't try but may be you can try to set a line-height value or you can test it without a text.

Comment: the same issue exists on an iphone as well.

Comment: It relates to `display: table-cell`, make it `display: block` and it works. Use a different method for vertically aligning the text?